# How to debug Chromium in Eclipse on Linux?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, google-chrome, eclipse-cdt, chromium

To debug chromium using gdb ([LinuxDebugging](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxDebugging)) one can use

```
chromium --renderer-cmd-prefix="gdb --args"
```

and

```
chromium --plugin-launcher="gdb --args"
```

Chromium then launches debugger with "gdb --args" and pass command line specifying how to launch that process. Then I can use gdb from command line as normally.

How can I achieve the same scenario in Eclipse?

By using non-stop mode I can debug chrome as usual. But since renderer and plugins are running out of process, I can't track them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I've found is "attach to process" approach.

**Update**: seems like Eclipse Indigo (gdb 7.2) supports [multiprocess](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_use_multi-process_debugging.3F) debugging.
Didn't try it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse can be used on Linux as an IDE for developing Chromium. This is from official google link:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxEclipseDev

Comment: This guide lacks information on how to debug Chromium itself. After the release of gdb with multiprocess debugging this question has become pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall anyone on the Chromium uses Eclipse with Chrome for debugging. With that technique, you can only use gdb.

Eclipse is not a supported environment, if you can support it, it would be super :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Qtcreator to debug chrome on linux, you need to just attach the process.

Comment: Yes, I've already posted such answer. It works regardless IDE. Besides, I've asked about Eclipse solution.